# Java int data type automatic conversion when using binary value

Tags: java

See the following example:

```
int a = 0111;

System.out.println(a);

Output: 73
```

Why is this happening and how can i get the exact value without conversion?

Comment: use `0b111` to get the binary value.

Comment: I tried, it outputs as 7.

Comment: Oh sorry about duplication, as this question was not easy to make others understand, but can you please explain how can i get the exact value.

Comment: what do you define as exact value? what should the output look like?

Comment: The output should look like 0111, I am going to use this value to convert it to string "0111" and then carry out some further process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Java Language Specification [3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), there are 4 ways to write an integer literal:

- *DecimalNumeral:* Digit `1-9` followed by zero or more digits `0-9`, or the number `0`.
- *HexNumeral:* Leading `0x` followed by one or more hexadecimal digits (`0-9`, `a-f`). Not case-sensitive.
- *OctalNumeral:* Digit `0` followed by one or more digits `0-7`.
- *BinaryNumeral:* Leading `0b` followed by one or more digits `0` or `1`. Not case-sensitive.

<sup>(All 4 allow underscores for clarity)</sup>

As you can see, the number `111` depends on the *prefix*:
`0111` (*OctalNumeral*) is `1*8*8 + 1*8 + 1` = `64+8+1` = **`73`**.
`111` (*DecimalNumeral*) is `1*10*10 + 1*10 + 1` = `100+10+1` = **`111`**.
`0b111` (*BinaryNumeral*) is `1*2*2 + 1*2 + 1` = `4+2+1` = **`7`**.
`0x111` (*HexNumeral*) is `1*16*16 + 1*16 + 1` = `256+16+1` = **`273`**.

Which one is right depends on what you wanted.

Comment: How to stop the conversion and get the exact output as 0111 ?

Comment: Getting a leading zero on *output* is a formatting problem. Number don't have leading zeroes. To get leading zero on output, use `printf("%04d", 111)` or the underlying `s = String.format("%04d", 111)`.

Answer (score 2):

Well you're getting the precise value. The problem is the format.

```
0111
```

gets interpreted as octal value in java. So your value actually **is** 73 as a quick calculation would show.

A octal value in java is defined this way:

```
OctalNumeral:
    0 OctalDigits
    0 Underscores OctalDigits
```

[jls 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

So `0_111` would be interpreted in the same way.

The format to use in java code would be:

```
0b111
```

Which actually gets interpreted as 7 - [in binary format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html) - , as expected.

I'll add the links later on, I'm in a bit of a hurry.